# How to call java service in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring

I'm new to ReactJS and want to call a service from Java. Here is my code

Cat021TrackHistoryService.java

```
public void export(){
    LocalDate yesterday = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1L);
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate theDate = yesterday;

    Instant startOfDay = theDate.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    Instant endOfDay = LocalTime.MAX.atDate(theDate).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    log.debug("Backup Time Parameter from {} to {}", startOfDay, endOfDay);
    today.getMonthValue();

    housekeeping.backupCat021TrackHistory(startOfDay, endOfDay, backupRootFolder + "/" + theDate.getYear() + "/" + theDate.getMonthValue() + "/" + theDate.getDayOfMonth() + "/" + "cat021." + theDate.getDayOfMonth() + ".nuh");
    }
```

Cat021TrackHistoryResource.java

```
    @PutMapping("/cat-021-track-histories")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> exportCat021TrackHistory(@Valid @RequestBody Cat021TrackHistory cat021TrackHistory) throws URISyntaxException{
        LocalDate yesterday = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1L);
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate theDate = today;

        Instant startOfDay = theDate.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        Instant endOfDay = LocalTime.MAX.atDate(theDate).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

        cat021TrackHistoryService.export();

        log.debug("Backup Time Parameter from {} to {}", startOfDay, endOfDay);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HeaderUtil.createAlert(applicationName, "OK",ENTITY_NAME)).build();
}
```

cat-021-track-history.tsx

```
<Link to={`${match.url}/export`} className="btn btn-info float-right jh-export-entity" id="jh-export-entity">
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon="file-export" />
  &nbsp; Export Cat 021 Track History
</Link>
```

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import ErrorBoundaryRoute from 'app/shared/error/error-boundary-route';

import Cat021TrackHistory from './cat-021-track-history';
import Cat021TrackHistoryDetail from './cat-021-track-history-detail';
import Cat021TrackHistoryUpdate from './cat-021-track-history-update';
import Cat021TrackHistoryDeleteDialog from './cat-021-track-history-delete-dialog';

const Routes = ({ match }) => (
  <>
    <Switch>
      <ErrorBoundaryRoute exact path={`${match.url}/new`} component={Cat021TrackHistoryUpdate} />
      <ErrorBoundaryRoute exact path={`${match.url}/:id/edit`} component={Cat021TrackHistoryUpdate} />
      <ErrorBoundaryRoute exact path={`${match.url}/:id`} component={Cat021TrackHistoryDetail} />
<ErrorBoundaryRoute exact path={`${match.url}/export`} component={Cat021TrackHistory} />
      <ErrorBoundaryRoute path={match.url} component={Cat021TrackHistory} />
    </Switch>
    <ErrorBoundaryRoute path={`${match.url}/:id/delete`} component={Cat021TrackHistoryDeleteDialog} />
  </>
);

export default Routes;
```

cat-021-track-history-reducer.tsx

```
export const ACTION_TYPES = {
  FETCH_CAT021TRACKHISTORY_LIST: 'cat021TrackHistory/FETCH_CAT021TRACKHISTORY_LIST',
  FETCH_CAT021TRACKHISTORY: 'cat021TrackHistory/FETCH_CAT021TRACKHISTORY',
  EXPORT_CAT021TRACKHISTORY: 'cat021TrackHistory/EXPORT_CAT021TRACKHISTORY',

  RESET: 'cat021TrackHistory/RESET'
};


export const exportEntities: ICrudPutAction<ICat021TrackHistory> = entity => async dispatch => {
  const requestUrl = `${apiUrl}/export`;
  const result = await dispatch({
    type: ACTION_TYPES.EXPORT_CAT021TRACKHISTORY,
    payload: axios.post<ICat021TrackHistory>(apiUrl, cleanEntity(entity))
  });
  dispatch(getEntities());
  return result;
}
```

But when i click the export button, it says error 400 on the client side with error on the server side:

> Bad Request: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "export"

Is there something wrong with my code? Is there any way to integrate my java service code with reactjs? Any help is useful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: your error clearly states you are trying to send a string type value where the expected type of the value is long(integer). trying sending your request in correct format

Comment: so i need to use the id to export the database rather than export the file in bulk?

Comment: that depends on what your service is expecting...